# Illustrate homework (integral region with implicit region)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions, homework

I must integrate:
$$ \int \int_D x^2y^2 dx dy$$ in the first quadrant.

This is a triangle with vertices in $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

I tried to draw it in mathematica with implicit region:

```
R = ImplicitRegion[{x + y <= 1}, {x, y}]; 
Plot[R, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

This is wrong and in addition I want to highlight that it is in the first quadrant (highlight $x$ and $y$ axis.

Can someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x + y <= 1, x >= 0, y >= 0}, {x, y}]
```

You can then visualize the region with `RegionPlot[reg]`, or use it as the domain of an integral:

```
Integrate[x^2 y^2, Element[{x, y}, reg]]

(* Out: 1/180 *)
```

Comment: It works just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

But you don't *need* `ImplicitRegion`:

```
Integrate[x^2 y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1 - x}]
```

(*

1/180

*)